# C# breaking execution of program

Tags: c#, web-applications

Is there any functionality in C# with Web, so that from UI, if a button is pressed, the execution should get stopped. (Here C# is already busy with some process execution)

For example:

```
while (something)
{
    // do something
}

while (something)
{
    // do something
}
```

If first while loop is under execution and from UI "stop execution" button is pressed then it should interrupt the whole execution and exit.

Comment: Well, sure.  If you are not using a CancellationToken then you are probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
private volatile bool _stop = false;

void OnCancelClick()
{
    _stop = true;
}

void WorkerProcess()  //In separate thread
{
    while (!_stop)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

There are a million ways to do it. This is probably the simplest to understand.

Comment: Will this work if I am already running my c# code from background and if a cancel button is pressed then it should stop the execution ?

Comment: Why not try it and see?